# Javascript onbeforeunload issue on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tabs, onbeforeunload

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var redirectFlag = false;
    if (+localStorage.tabCount > 0) {
        alert('Already a tab or window opened!');
        redirectFlag = true;
    } else {
        redirectFlag = false;
        localStorage.tabCount = 0;
    }
    localStorage.tabCount = +localStorage.tabCount + 1;
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        localStorage.tabCount = +localStorage.tabCount - 1;
    };
    if (redirectFlag) {
        var baseUrl = window.location.origin;
        window.location.href = baseUrl + 'mylocation';
    }
</script>
```

I want to check if another tab is opened or not. This script works on firefox and chrome. But on IE 11 the `window.onbeforeunload` is ignored.

Is there a workaround to do this for IE as well ? Thank you

Comment: What kinda errors are  you getting? If any?

Comment: I m not getting any errors

Comment: Have you tried something like... `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(){ ......some magic happening here...... });`

Comment: I tried with `addEventListener` and it is ignored

Answer (score 2):

There are several known issues with `beforeunload` event. Here are some of them:

> Attaching an event handler/listener to window or document's beforeunload event prevents browsers from using in-memory page navigation caches, like [Firefox's Back-Forward cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/1.5/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching) or [WebKit's Page Cache](https://webkit.org/blog/516/webkit-page-cache-ii-the-unload-event/).
>
> To combat unwanted pop-ups, browsers may not display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with, or **may even not display them at all**.
>
> Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

It is recommended to use [`pageHide` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pagehide) instead, if target browser supports it. You can find about its support here: https://caniuse.com/#search=pagehide

So instead of reducing the `localStorage.tabCount` in `onbeforeunload` event handler, you should use `onpagehide`:

```
window.onpagehide = function () {
  localStorage.tabCount = +localStorage.tabCount - 1;
};
```

You can try the following code pen to see if it works for you:
https://codepen.io/Nisargshah02/pen/eMXMGE?editors=1011

---

I am not fully sure regarding your approach - i.e. if maintaining the count in localStorage is ideal. In past I have used a library [Crosstab](https://github.com/tejacques/crosstab) for the purpose, and it has proved to be reliable.

---

**Note**: It is a bad practice to access localStorge items through property-like accessor `localStorage.tabCount`. One of the common issues you can run into would be someone overriding system methods such as `getItem` or `setItem`.

Comment: The `onpagehide` it works on firefox and chrome, but not in IE 11

Comment: @Chester I think IE has some issues with the way localStorage is shared between tabs. Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22518785/5894241

Comment: @Chester It looks like the issue is with Iframes only, which explains why Codepen isn't working as expected. If you are not using iframes in your page, you shouldn't see any issues. Issue documentation: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/110656/

Answer (score 0):

This way it works for IE11 and latest firefox ,chrome. Didn't check for opera,edge, safari or netscape.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //only when an order is created
    var redirectFlag = false;
    if (+localStorage.tabCount > 0) {
        alert('Already a tab or window opened!');
        redirectFlag = true;
    } else {
        localStorage.tabCount = 0;
    }
    localStorage.tabCount = +localStorage.tabCount + 1;
    //works for firefox;chrome;ie11
    window.addEventListener('onpagehide', function (evt) {
        localStorage.tabCount = +localStorage.tabCount - 1;
    });
    //redirect user if there are 2 tabs/windows opened
    if (redirectFlag) {
        var baseUrl = window.location.origin;
        window.location.href = baseUrl + 'myurl';
    }
</script>
```